# GeoDjango and Geoserver tutorial or book suggestion for beginner

Tags: web, gis, geoserver, geodjango

I am beginner to python. I would like to work on land information system. can you please suggest me some basic tutorial or book for beginner. thank you in advance!

I am expecting you to suggest me some beginner level basic tutorial or book to start my project

Comment: Sorry, asking for book or tutorial suggestions is off-topic